# can't deploy Google Cloud Endpoints 2.0 on existing service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have had a Python-based Google App Engine app working great using Cloud Endpoints 1.0 for several years without incident.  I have had nothing but trouble migrating to Cloud Endpoints 2.0.

Currently I'm in the following state after already clearing many previous hurdles described in other similar questions:

- I have one version of my service called **gce1** which uses Endpoints 1.0 and is set as the default service receiving 100% of my traffic.  I can point API clients and the APIs Explorer to both `gce1-dot-myservice.appspot.com` and the default `myservice.appspot.com` and everything works fine.  I can verify in the logs that anything that goes through here is using GCE 1.0.
- I have a second version of my service called **gce2** which is not receiving any traffic by default, but if I point an API client or the APIs Explorer to `gce2-dot-myservice.appspot.com` it works just fine, and I can verify in the logs that anything that goes through here is using GCE 2.0.

Great, right?  So it would seem that all I need to do is migrate all my traffic to `gce2` and I'm done.

But... when I do that everything breaks!  The default `myservice.appspot.com` serves up `405 POST Method Not Allowed` responses to my existing clients, and if I look at the APIs Explorer, suddenly it now shows a bunch of obsolete methods that I think are from years ago and are no longer used in my current API.  I can't tell where those are coming from (they are nowhere in my code, and haven't been for years), and I can't get the default service to serve the GCE 2.0 API no matter what I do.

The biggest problem is that I have thousands of users in the wild that all point to the default API URL, so it isn't so easy to just have them start pointing to `gce2-dot-myservice`, and besides, it doesn't make sense that I can't make the new default the new default. I've been working on this migration to GCE 2.0 for months, the deadline for getting off GCE 1.0 is getting closer by the day, and Google Support has not responded since late last year on this topic.

I should also mention I have tried:

- Pushing a new service with the GCE2.0 code directly to default
- Pushing a new service with no API at all (to maybe clear a cache or something)
- Pushing services with all different sorts of version names

None of these have worked, although I haven't done any of them allowing a long delay since I'm working on a live service with real users.

Comment: Are you on Java or Python? Likely you're encountering a known issue with a fix rolling out soon.

Comment: I'm using Python. Will this fix be something that requires a new push with new code on my part, or something that will just change in production and then this will work after that?

Comment: It won't require a code change. It will only require you to change default certain again. That's where the bug is. I'll update this question when the fix is released.

Comment: Hey saiyr, is there a Public Issue Tracker referencing this issue?

Comment: @saiyr no luck - I'm seeing the exact same thing as if nothing has changed.

Comment: @saiyr also - the link to the "public" issue requires a Google corp login

Comment: Sorry, here is the correct link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76031966 Please comment there. Or you can perhaps see my email there and contact me directly with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now resolved, so for most people it should no longer occur. However, in my specific case, I had a legacy API that was getting in the way and had to be deleted, which did require specific attention from a Google engineer.

If you have similar issues, visit [issuetracker.google.com/issues/76031966](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76031966) and comment there.

Thanks to @saiyr for help tracking this down.